# Sharing rule causes sibling access leakage

Tags: sharing-rule, roles, userrecordaccess

(I actually think this might be a bug...)

*Note: Org-wide defaults on accounts/contacts/opportunities/cases are all set to "Private".*

I have the following role hierarchy:

[image]

As expected, Team Lead 3 cannot see contacts owned by Team Lead 2, even if Team Lead 3 owns the account.

However, if I create the following sharing rule...

[image]

...suddenly **Team Lead 3** AND **Team 3 / Group 2 BDA** can see **all contacts** (not opportunities or accounts) owned by the other Team Leads AND their subordinates.  If I delete this rule, the sibling access issue goes away.  I don't understand how a sibling's access would be exposed when it is on a completely different hierarchy than the roles in the rule.

Does anyone have any insight?  Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: if you click on the Share button for a Contact record now visible to Team 3/ Group 2 BDA you can see the reasons why SFDC is exposing that Contact